# Pandas Dataframe Groupby with multiple columns and sum it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas.excelwriter

I have a dataframe df which i need to groupby multiple column based on a condition.

**Input**

| Employee Name | Subjects | Billable | Hours | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anu | Java | Yes | 8 | 01-03-2021 |
| Anu | Python | Yes | 9 | 02-03-2021 |
| Anu | SQL | No | 6 | 03-03-2021 |
| Anu | React | Yes | 5 | 03-03-2021 |
| Anu | .Net | No | 8 | 04-03-2021 |
| Bala | SQL | No | 5 | 01-03-2021 |
| Bala | Python | Yes | 4 | 01-03-2021 |
| Bala | Java | Yes | 2 | 02-03-2021 |
| Bala | .Net | No | 8 | 03-03-2021 |
| Bala | React | Yes | 7 | 04-03-2021 |

**Columns should be add in output file**: Utilization, Billable Utilization, Non-Billable Utilization

1. Calculation for Utilization columns : Utilization = df[Hours]/9*100

-> If billable column value as "**YES**"" - create column as Billable utilization

2. Calculation for Billable Utilization in column: Billable Utilization = df[Hours]/9 * 100

-> If billable column value as "**NO**"" - create column as Non-Billable utilization

3. Calculation for Non-Billing Utilization in column: Non-Billable Utilization = df[Hours]/9*100

**Code**

```
available =9
utilization= (df['Hours']/available*100).round(2)
df = df.assign(Utilization = utilization)
df1 = df.groupby(['Date','Employee Name'])['Utilization'].sum()
df['Billable'] = np.where(df['Billable'] == 'Yes', 'Billable Utilization','Non Billable Utilization')
df2 = (df.groupby(['Date','Employee Name']).agg({'Hours':sum}).div(available).mul(100)).round(2)
```

**Expected Output**
[image: Expected Output]

**My output**

[image: My Output]

Comment: In your input dataframe you're missing the column `"Utilization"`. Can you edit your question and add it?

Comment: @AndrejKesely - Utilization column is not a input data...

Comment: @Gomathi Is the `Utilzation` column in final output sum of  `Billable` and `Non Billable` Utilization?

Comment: @Shubham Sharma Yes Utilization is Sum of Total hours.

Comment: @Gomathi Are you sure the expected output is correct? For example `Bala` on the date `04-03-2021` has billable "yes" and in your output is in non-billable column.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would put `input` as code `df = DataFrame(....input data...)` so we could run it.

Comment: @AndrejKesely- Now its corrected.. Thanks.. Kindly guide me to resolve it

Comment: @Gomathi The expected output is still wrong check the values at row `2` and `3`, The `billable` utilization should be `44.44` and `100` respectively.

Comment: Why some `Utilization` is split into two? Like `100 -> 55.56 44.44`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma : Thanks , Now its expected output is corrected. Kindly help me..

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, as per business logic need to split into two columns

Comment: @Gomathi *per business logic* What logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "pivot" `Hours` into `Billable` and `Non-Billable` columns using [**`pivot_table()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and then convert to utilization:

```py
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Employee Name':{0:'Anu',1:'Anu',2:'Anu',3:'Anu',4:'Anu',5:'Bala',6:'Bala',7:'Bala',8:'Bala',9:'Bala'},'Subjects':{0:'Java',1:'Python',2:'SQL',3:'React',4:'.Net',5:'SQL',6:'Python',7:'Java',8:'.Net',9:'React'},'Billable':{0:'Yes',1:'Yes',2:'No',3:'Yes',4:'No',5:'No',6:'Yes',7:'Yes',8:'No',9:'Yes'},'Hours':{0:8,1:9,2:6,3:5,4:8,5:5,6:4,7:2,8:8,9:7},'Date':{0:'01-03-2021',1:'02-03-2021',2:'03-03-2021',3:'03-03-2021',4:'04-03-2021',5:'01-03-2021',6:'01-03-2021',7:'02-03-2021',8:'03-03-2021',9:'04-03-2021'}})

# pivot hours into (non)billable
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Date', 'Employee Name'], columns='Billable').reset_index()
df.columns = ['Date', 'Employee Name', 'Non-Billable', 'Billable']

# compute utilization
df['Non-Billable'] = df['Non-Billable'].div(9).mul(100).round(2)
df['Billable'] = df['Billable'].div(9).mul(100).round(2)
df['Utilization'] = df[['Billable', 'Non-Billable']].fillna(0).sum(axis=1)

#          Date Employee Name  Non-Billable  Billable  Utilization
# 0  01-03-2021           Anu           NaN     88.89        88.89
# 1  01-03-2021          Bala         55.56     44.44       100.00
# 2  02-03-2021           Anu           NaN    100.00       100.00
# 3  02-03-2021          Bala           NaN     22.22        22.22
# 4  03-03-2021           Anu         66.67     55.56       122.23
# 5  03-03-2021          Bala         88.89       NaN        88.89
# 6  04-03-2021           Anu         88.89       NaN        88.89
# 7  04-03-2021          Bala           NaN     77.78        77.78
```